# Regular Expression to match text between HTML tags

Tags: regex

I have to parse a table in HTML code using Regex. However, the code for these tables can differ because they come from different sources. But, they all have in common that they only use 2 columns. So what I want to do is to match all text that is not encapsulated within the '<' and '>' symbols.

Moreover, I want to name the two columns / groups in Regex.

I have this table row for example:

```
<tr>
  <td width="313" valign="top" style="width:234.9pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt">
    <p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>Company</o:p></p>
  </td>

  <td width="313" valign="top" style="width:234.9pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-left:none;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt">
    <p class="MsoNormal">TestCompany<o:p></o:p></p>
  </td>
</tr>
```

For which I only want to select 'Company' and 'TestCompany' and name these matches as 'Key' and 'Value' respectively.

I came up with the following Regex:

https://regex101.com/r/09fpbz/2

However, this also selects odd tags like `</o:p>` and spaces/new lines.

Comment: HTML is not a regular language.  Are you sure you wouldn't prefer an HTML parser, software that is specifically designed for this purpose?

Comment: "I have to parse a table in HTML code using Regex." Search stackoverflow on this subject and you will see this is the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

If `<o:p>` are always like in your exemple it will work.

```
<tr>(?:[^<]*<){3}[^>]+>(?<Key>[\w\w]+)(?:[^>]*>){5}(?<Value>[\w\s]+)
```